# JS Error : [Deprecation] Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user's experience

Tags: javascript, jquery

When I click the button second time, then it shows the below warning:-

*VM751 jquery-3.5.0.js:9987 [Deprecation] Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user's experience. For more help, check https://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/.*

```
send @ VM751 jquery-3.5.0.js:9987
ajax @ VM751 jquery-3.5.0.js:9682
jQuery._evalUrl @ VM751 jquery-3.5.0.js:9857
domManip @ VM751 jquery-3.5.0.js:6123
append @ VM751 jquery-3.5.0.js:6264
$.fn.add_title_section @ w2mm_cards.js:324
(anonymous) @ VM747 w2mm_cards.js:351
dispatch @ VM751 jquery-3.5.0.js:5429
elemData.handle @ VM751 jquery-3.5.0.js:5233
```

This is code:-

```
var add_title_content = $(".add-title-content");
var mobile_section = $("#mobile-other-section");
$.fn.add_title_section = function () {
        // For desktop
        var first = $("#first-column");
        var second = $("#second-column");
        var third = $("#third-column");
        second.html("");
        second.show();
        add_title_content.show();
        second.append(add_title_content);
        first.removeClass();
        first.addClass("col-md-12 col-lg-4 round-content");
        third.removeClass();
        third.addClass("col-md-12 col-lg-4 round-content");
        
        $('.value-truncate').removeClass("truncated");
        $('.value-truncate').addClass("truncated-mobile");

        //For mobile
        var home_section = $(".mobile-home");
        home_section.hide();
        home_section.removeClass("hide-section");
        mobile_section.html("");
        mobile_section.append(add_title_content.clone(true));
        mobile_section.show();
        add_title_content.show();
    } 

     
    $(document).on("click", ".btn-add", function (e) {
        $.fn.add_title_section();
        e.stopImmediatePropagation();
    });
```

Comment: It looks like `add_title_content` contains an inline script, which makes a synchronous AJAX call. You've to change the call asynchronous. When that script is inserted to the DOM, it will be a part of the "main thread", though the error occurs on a button click.

Comment: And what's your question?   It's all explained in the message.  Stop using synchronous requests.

Comment: Relevant: https://forum.jquery.com/topic/why-does-evalurl-use-async-false

Comment: @freedomn-m A nice catch, it's jQuery making the AJAX call when reading a script, the error is not due to OP's code in `add_title_content ` (except it adds a script with `src`).

Comment: @Teemu can you tell me please what change should I do in code?

Comment: @JasmeetPabla As it seems to be a jQuery issue, I can't say much. One way would be to remove the script tag(s) from `add_title_content` and include the script(s) to the original markup. This might require some changes to those scripts, but that depends on what they're doing on the page. Another way would be to dynamically add the script tag(s), but without knowing the code all fixes are just speculations. You could edit your post, and add the `add_title_content` string.

Comment: @Teemu I want to show you the complete code of js file. So that you can help me to resolve it. Where can I show you the code?

Comment: Just edit the question, and add the relevant part of the code. If there's a ton of code, just strip all the irrelevant parts of it.

Comment: @Teemu can I use pastebin to show u code?

Comment: The question should stand on its own content, but maybe we can make an exception ...

Comment: @Teemu the code I wrote in question shows warning when I clicked the button second time. Other code is not related to this.

Comment: At the first time there's probably no script tags in `add_title_content`. Creating HTML from a string is always error prone, real dynamic element creation might also resolve the issue.

Comment: @Teemu I added two statements as first 2 lines in above code. Please check and help me.

Comment: Remove the script tag from the element, and place it at the end of the body.

Comment: @Teemu add_title_content is a div element placed in html file.

Comment: The error message tells, that the div contains a scipt tag too.

Comment: ok i will try to improve code.

Comment: @Teemu yes you are right. I removed script tag and now no warning occurs. It works fine. Thank you very very much for helping me.

Answer (score 1):

Synchronous requests block the thread. If you run it on the main thread, and the request takes a long time, the whole browser tab will freeze. Therefor, it is deprecated.

Best solution is to make the request async (which is the default). Other option is to open a worker thread with is much harder.

Comment: Rani Sharmin what should I with code, can you please tell me?

Comment: Not without seeing the rest of your code.